# BO: Is it possible to add some automatical text when defining schedule in its title?

Tags: business-objects

[image: Title section where I wish to add automatical text]

In the title of schedule I wish to see timestamp with the date of its execution.

I wonder if there is some kind of autotext that can be added in title section that would return execution date. Like @DATE or soemthing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Instance Title* cannot be customised with variables or placeholders.

However, depending on the format and the destination you selected, you can use placeholders (such as `DateTime`) to the resulting filename as you can see in the screenshot below.

This example is configured with *Adobe Acrobat (PDF)* as format and the *File System* as destination.

[image: Placeholders]